# Python 3 causes memory error at shuffle(X,Y) where X is 36000 3-channel images (36000, 256,256,3) and Y is 3-channel normal data (36000, 256,256,3)

Tags: python, deep-learning, out-of-memory

Following image showing Memory Usage:
[image: Image showing Memory Usage]
Memory error occurs. I am using Numpy and Python3. I have two numpy arrays of shape (36000,256,256,3) each as X and Y and memory error occurs when I do following code. They are code to prepare training data. Is there another way to do it which uses lesser memory?

This is my processor: `Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz × 32`

The error is shown in : `X, Y = shuffle(X,Y)`

```py
X = []
Y = []

    for im , normal in zip(images,normals) :
        image =  getImageArr(dir_resize_mRGB + im , 256 , 256 ) 
        X.append(image)
        Y.append( getNormalArr( dir_resize_mNormal + normal , 256 , 256 )  )

    X, Y = np.array(X) , np.array(Y)


    print(X.shape)

    X_min = np.min(X)
    X_max = np.max(X)

    X = (X-X_min)/(X_max-X_min)
    print('min:{}, max:{}'.format(X_min, X_max))

    train_rate = 0.85
    np.random.seed(42)
    index_train = np.random.choice(X.shape[0],int(X.shape[0]*train_rate),replace=False)
    index_test  = list(set(range(X.shape[0])) - set(index_train))

    X, Y = shuffle(X,Y)
    X_train, y_train = X[index_train],Y[index_train]
    X_test, y_test = X[index_test],Y[index_test]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "our_train_normal.py", line 312, in <module>
    X, Y = shuffle(X,Y)
  File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 403, in shuffle
    return resample(*arrays, **options)
  File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 327, in resample
    resampled_arrays = [safe_indexing(a, indices) for a in arrays]
  File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 327, in <listcomp>
    resampled_arrays = [safe_indexing(a, indices) for a in arrays]
  File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 216, in safe_indexing
    return X.take(indices, axis=0)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Perhaps there is another shuffle somewhere defined, but what I used to have second parameter as Random Numbers Generator, nor numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if this is a custom `shuffle` function or the `numpy.random.shuffle` [which](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) seems to take in only one array.

If you are running into `Out Of Memory` error, you should first try sub-sampling your arrays, like `X = X[100, :]` and `Y = Y[100, :]`, and verify that this is indeed due to exceeding memory.

In order to shuffle two arrays by the same order, I will suggest using `numpy.random.permutation` [which](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) will give you a list of indices.

```
shuff_indx = numpy.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
X = X[shuff_indx, :]
Y = Y[shuff_indx, :]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response sir. I am using : from sklearn.utils import shuffle. How can I use it to get the train and test arrays with the method you provided? In other words, how do I replace these statements if I follow your method of shuffling.  X_train, y_train = X[index_train],Y[index_train]
    X_test, y_test = X[index_test],Y[index_test]

Comment: Once you have shuffled your arrays, you can continue using the other statements as it is. The code I mentioned will replace your line `X, Y = shuffle(X,Y)`.